# Selection/Edit menu in React Native

Tags: react-native

In iOS it's possible to configure a Selection and Edit Menu. That looks like this:
[image: selection_menu]

Also, the API is displayed here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html

So is this possible on React Native? I am building a chat app where we need to allow copying messages and also custom menu items.

Comment: Did you ever find out if this was possible from React Native?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, customising the edit menu is achieved through `UIMenuController`.
However if we look at the react-native repo the only occurrence of that class (until today) can be found in the [RCTTextView class](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UIMenuController&type=).

If you want to use it for other components you'll have to [bridge it yourself](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html).

[Some 3rd party libraries exist](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/need-to-implement-uimenucontroller).