# Handle Context Menu on selectable Text in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, contextmenu, react-native-text

I am trying to modify context menu that shows up in selectable of `<Text />` in react-native. I want to do that specifically in js. It should select multiple words so that I can make api query using those words.

There are other solutions using java -

[Disable EditText context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673185/disable-edittext-context-menu)

[React Native | add option to Text context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883406/react-native-add-option-to-text-context-menu?rq=1)

[Selection/Edit menu in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845503/selection-edit-menu-in-react-native)

But these are not quite helpful..

Comment: did you find any solution?